# Troubleshooting MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-query

Can anybody tell me how to troubleshoot a MongoDB running as a container?

We have the problem that our mongoDB is running out of 300% CPU...continuously. The processes slow down the entire system ans also the Memory fully utilized.

I'm not so familiar with the MongoDB and would be very grateful for approaches that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use query profiler to identify slow queries  (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/). Another way is to look at running queries using `db.currentOp()` (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.currentOp/).

After you identify slow queries you can use `cursor.explain()` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) function to check if the query uses the right index. If not reorder filters in query or add missing indexes.

Comment: Hey Marek! Thank you very much, i will try it!